# \rule or \hrule extending into innerrightmargin of mdframed box

Tags: rules, mdframed

I have an `mdframed` box with a large `innerrightmargin` (which, in the place I use this, will contain various `\marginpar` entries, and I need this functionality to remain).

I'd like to have a rule that extends across (most of) the width of `innerrightmargin`. For the sake of something specific, in the MWE below I'd like a rule extending across all but 0.2cm at either side.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newmdenv[linewidth=1pt,innerrightmargin=2.2cm,innerleftmargin=0.2cm,
          linecolor=black,backgroundcolor=yellow!20]{yellowbox}

\begin{document}

% Box without rules for comparison
\begin{yellowbox}
\lipsum[2]
\end{yellowbox}

% Box with \rule looks right, but returns overfull hbox
\begin{yellowbox}
\lipsum[2]

\noindent\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth+2cm}{2pt}
\end{yellowbox}

% Box with \hrule makes the yellowbox wider
\begin{yellowbox}
\lipsum[2]

\hrule height 2pt width \dimexpr\textwidth+2cm
\end{yellowbox}

\end{document}
```

See image below for output: The first box is just for comparison. The use of a `\rule` in the second box looks correct, but returns an overfull hbox. The final one uses an `\hrule`. This final one would be my preferred method, but it currently causes the width of the box to expand by 2cm to accommodate the rule.

Any suggestions?

[image: Output of MWE above]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newmdenv[linewidth=1pt,innerrightmargin=2.2cm,innerleftmargin=0.2cm,
          linecolor=black,backgroundcolor=yellow!20]{yellowbox}

\begin{document}

% Box without rules for comparison
\begin{yellowbox}
\lipsum[2]
\end{yellowbox}

% Box with \rule looks right
\begin{yellowbox}
\lipsum[2]

\noindent\rlap{\rule{\dimexpr\textwidth+2cm}{2pt}}%
\end{yellowbox}


\end{document}
```

Comment: How have I never come across `\rlap` before? With a little tinkering for the situation I actually need it in, this works nicely, thanks! Is there a good reason that `\hrule` affects the width of an `mdframed` box?

Comment: @RobertBrignall by default the box is as wide as its content, (rlap makes a box of zero size that silently overlaps on the right, hence the name so the outer box doesn't see it) the \rule construct doesn't make a box that forces the outer box wider as it is a paragraph (hence the `\noindent` so the paragraph is wrapped to lines `\hsize` long, it is _that_ box that is then overfull, but the paragraph containing the `\rule` is the text width size so doesn't force the frame wider `\hrule` doesn't make a paragraph so directly affects the frame